# Cannot implicitly convert type 'NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Indicators.QuickTradeObject' How do i fix it

Tags: c#

I have declared my list as below

```
 private List<QuickTradeObject> AllTrades = new List<QuickTradeObject>();
```

When i am deserializing my json, i get a cast error. how do i fix it?

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
     string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
   AllTrades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuickTradeObject>(jsonString); 
}
```

NinjaScript File    Error   Code    Line    Column
PlotTrades.cs   Cannot implicitly convert type 'NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Indicators.QuickTradeObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'  CS0029  72  16

```js
#region Using declarations
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using NinjaTrader.Cbi;
using NinjaTrader.Gui;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.Chart;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.SuperDom;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.Tools;
using NinjaTrader.Data;
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript;
using NinjaTrader.Core.FloatingPoint;
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.DrawingTools;
#endregion
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

//This namespace holds Indicators in this folder and is required. Do not change it. 
namespace NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Indicators
{
 public class PlotTrades : Indicator
 {
  private Series<double> EntryPrice;
  private Series<double> ExitPrice;
  private Series<DateTime> EntryTime;
  private Series<DateTime> ExitTime;
  private Series<string> TradeDirection;
   private List<QuickTradeObject> AllTrades = new List<QuickTradeObject>();
  private string filename=@"c:\temp\2019-10-12--08-58-41EURUSDVShapedBreakout.json.json";

  protected override void OnStateChange()
  {
   if (State == State.SetDefaults)
   {
    Description         = @"Enter the description for your new custom Indicator here.";
    Name          = "PlotTrades";
    Calculate         = Calculate.OnBarClose;
    IsOverlay         = true;
    DisplayInDataBox       = true;
    DrawOnPricePanel       = true;
    DrawHorizontalGridLines      = true;
    DrawVerticalGridLines      = true;
    PaintPriceMarkers       = true;
    ScaleJustification       = NinjaTrader.Gui.Chart.ScaleJustification.Right;
    //Disable this property if your indicator requires custom values that cumulate with each new market data event. 
    //See Help Guide for additional information.
    IsSuspendedWhileInactive     = true;
    AddLine(Brushes.Orange, 1, "Equity");
   }
   else if (State == State.Configure)
   {
   }
   else if (State == State.DataLoaded)
   {    
    EntryPrice = new Series<double>(this);
    ExitPrice = new Series<double>(this);
    EntryTime = new Series<DateTime>(this);
    ExitTime = new Series<DateTime>(this);
    TradeDirection = new Series<string>(this);
    
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
     string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
   AllTrades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuickTradeObject>(jsonString); 
}
 Print(   AllTrades.ToString()); 
    
   }
  }

  protected override void OnBarUpdate()
  {
   //Add your custom indicator logic here.
  }

 }
 public  class QuickTradeObject
    {
   public DateTime sessionDate;
  public int TradeNumber; 
        public DateTime entryTime;
        public DateTime exitTime;
        public DateTime halfExitTime;
        public double entryPrice;
        public double halfExitPrice;
        public double fullExitPrice;
        public string Direction;
  public double highestHigh;
  public double lowestLow;
   public double gains;
  public double risk;
  public double mfe;
  public double mae;
  public double todayTarget;
  public double todayTargetRemainingatStart;
  public double todayTargetRemainingatEnd;
  public double cumulativeGainsToday;
  public double cumulativeMAEtoday;
  public double cumulativeMFEtoday;
  public bool MeetTargetToday;
  public double reEntryTimeinMinutes;
  public double timeInTrade;
  public bool reEnteredSameDirection;
  public bool CrossedWeekend;
  public bool trigger50Percenttail;
  public bool pulledBackin5;
  public bool movedBackin5;
  public bool movedStop45;
  public double MaxMoveBeforePullback;
  public double MaxMoveAgainstAfterPullback;
  public DateTime pulledBackin5Time;
  public DateTime movedBackinTime;
        public string url;
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

fixed it by using the following
 AllTrades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(jsonString);